# Making multiple parts of a SpannableStringBuilder Bold

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, spannablestring, spannable

I am trying to get a string in a TextView which should look like this:

> **BOLD** not bold **BOLD** not bold

I have tried this code:

```
val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
val boldSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
val spanFlag = Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE

builder.append("BOLD ", boldSpan, spanFlag)
builder.append("not bold ")
builder.append("BOLD ", boldSpan, spanFlag)
builder.append("not bold ")

return builder
```

The problem is it's only bolding the last part. Result looks like this:

> BOLD not bold **BOLD** not bold

Is there any way to bold multiple parts using a SpannableStringBuilder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two different spans:

```
val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
val spanFlag = Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE

builder.append("BOLD ", StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), spanFlag)
builder.append("not bold ")
builder.append("BOLD ", StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), spanFlag)
builder.append("not bold ")

return builder
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this, thanks a lot it works like a charm!